# typegoose/mongoose date format for rest api

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, typegoose

I'm using typescript for a server coupled to a mongodb.

I am strictly defining the outputs with an openapi file.

With mongoose i am very familiar with defining dates eg:

```
  birthday: Date;
```

and now with Typegoose:

```
  @prop()
  birthday: Date;
```

So far so good, except when i need to output from my express typescript server eg:

```js
  public async generateLoginTokensAndHttpResponse (userDoc: User, req: any): Promise<Login> {
    const renewalToken = JwtService.generateRenewalToken(userDoc);
    await JwtRepository.createNewJwt(userDoc._id, renewalToken, req.clientIp, req.headers['user-agent']);
    return {
      tokenAccess: {
        value: JwtService.generateAccessToken(userDoc),
      },
      tokenRenewal: {
        value: renewalToken,
      },
      user: userDoc,
    };
  }
```

Where the interface "Login" looks like this (generated based on a swagger definition):

```js
export default interface Login {
  user: {
    verified: boolean;
    email: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    username: string;
    captchaLocked: boolean;
    birthday?: string;
  };
  tokenAccess: { value: string };
  tokenRenewal: { value: string };
}
```

If I change the `birthday?: string;` to `birthday?: Date;` it is ok, but then this breaks the expected output of the swagger defintition:

```
type: string
format: date-time
```

It would be expensive to iterate overall objects calling a function to transform all date objects to date-time strings..

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `JSON.stringify` / `JSON.parse`, it will convert Dates from/to strings

Comment: Where in the application though? Is there way to automagically do this without impacting performance?

Comment: when you use "nestjs", you can use transformers, if you use "type-/graphql" mutations, if you use plain "express" you could use "middleware", and about performance - sorry i dont know